# Multiple condition with sub-query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE
     cityid IN (SELECT id FROM b)
  OR regionid IN (SELECT id FROM b)
  OR countryid IN (SELECT id FROM b)
```

Is there a way (using MySQL syntax) to avoid running the sub-query 3 times?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of  using subselects a join might be used

```
SELECT a.* FROM a 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN b 
       ON (a.cityid = b.id OR a.regionid = b.id or a.countryid = b.id) 
WHERE b.id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Nice. I would change the `LEFT` to `INNER JOIN` and drop the `WHERE b.id IS NOT NULL` alltogether.

Comment: This solves the specific case but it doesn't answer the general question. In cases where the subquery can't be replaced with a join, how do you express multiple comparisons with the result of the subquery without repeating the subquery? Still unanswered.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated:**

**1st try** was:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM a 
  LEFT JOIN b AS city 
    ON a.cityid = city.id
  LEFT JOIN b AS region
    ON a.regionid = region.id
  LEFT JOIN b AS country 
    ON a.countryid = country.id
```

which I think it's wrong because all rows of `a` will be shown with the above.

The correct way is I think KarlsFriend's one, or this

**2nd try:**

```
SELECT a.*
FROM a 
  INNER JOIN b 
    ON ( a.cityid = b.id OR a.regionid = b.id or a.countryid = b.id )
```

---

But either way you use, even your original one, I don't think that the query plan will include running the subquery `(SELECT id FROM b)` 3 times.